# Delphi XE5: image and size of the Smartphone screen

Tags: image, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

When I use TImageView component of the image within it is not appropriate to the size of the correct resolution of the mobile screen. For example, in some models the image becomes the white border on the top and bottom, on some devices the image is smaller than the screen, the other, add a piece of the image borders. How do I do that? There is some proportion to this problem and not deform the image or if I leave it on the component of fixed size?

Here are a few illustrations to understand better!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in a ScaledLayout and then in FormCreate method put this code

```
var
screenSize: TSize;
begin
  screenSize := Screen.Size;
  ScaledLayout1.Scale.X := screenSize.cx / ScaledLayout1.OriginalWidth;
  ScaledLayout1.Scale.Y := screenSize.cy / ScaledLayout1.OriginalHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you upgrade to Delphi XE7, you can resolve cross-platform screen size
by using FireUI.

Comment: This would probably make more sense as a comment than an answer, since it doesn't really answer the OPs question.